# AngularJS avoid HTML strip of directive tag

Tags: html, json, angularjs

Working with AngularJS, i have a json object with custom HTML, including a directive tag for use with Prism.

For example,

```
<pre><code  class="language-clike" prism> ... </code></pre>
```

This results in:

```
<pre><code class="language-clike"> ... </code></pre>
```

How can I avoid this?

I'm returning data the following way:

```
...
$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.page);
...
<article ng-bind-html="page.content"></article>
```

Answer (score 4):

When the DOM is ready use

```
Prism.highlightAll();
```